# UIRefreshControl crashes on pull down - Uncaught Exception Swift

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to implement the pull to refresh feature in my TableView app. However when I run the app, it crashes as soon as I pull down to refresh the page. I get the following message in the console:

```
2014-09-30 21:13:15.799 SimpleText[2031:601545] 17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
2014-09-30 21:13:45.296 SimpleText[2031:601545] -[SimpleText.TimelineTableViewController loadData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d50d5e0
2014-09-30 21:13:45.300 SimpleText[2031:601545] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SimpleText.TimelineTableViewControllerloadData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d50d5e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x189402084 0x198fb40e4 0x189409094 0x189405e48 0x18930b08c 0x18da6cb98 0x18da55dd8 0x18dba6834 0x100869158 0x100869118 0x100872320 0x100869118 0x10087cae4 0x10086af7c 0x10086cec8 0x1893b98dc 0x1893b7984 0x1892e5664 0x1923175a4 0x18da9e164 0x1001128b0 0x1001129bc 0x19962aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This confused me because I didn't think error handling was a part of swift, yet it is telling me the exception is uncaught?

Here is what my refresh code looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "loadData:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)

    //refresh posts when app is loaded
    self.loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take out the colon in "loadData:"

```
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "loadData", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Also make sure loadData isn't marked as a private method.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Do you know why the colon was not needed? Many other areas of my code I have needed the colon. For example `logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: "logout:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` I would never have thought to remove the colon due to using it so much in other places. Thank you very much!

Comment: You would need a colon if there are parameters in the method. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_38) isn't too clear with selectors in Swift.

Comment: Okay well thanks a lot for the help! Just curious, if I wanted to call the loadData method and also send the parameter `refreshControl`, do you know how I would do this? Because I need to call the `refreshControl!.endRefreshing()` in loadData

Comment: Usually I would have an implicitly unwrapped optional property on the view controller having a reference to the refreshControl to call endRefreshing()